# Alert Message Does Not Display After User Clicks Submit

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I'm brand new to coding and I was trying to complete my first project on CodePen. I cannot get my js code to respond to my html. I believe I linked the js page to the html page correctly, I inserted Bootstrap with jquery, and I can't see where I'm writing the actual code wrong so I have no idea why it's not doing anything

```js
$("#submit").click(function () ) {
  alert("Thank you for your message! I will respond as soon as I find somewhere with free wifi!");
  var userName = $("#userName").val();
  var userEmail = $("#userEmail").val();
  var userMessage = $("#userMessage").val();
}

$(".contact-header").hover(function () ) {
  $(".contact-header").css("color", "black");                          
}
```

```css
body{
  background-color: burlywood;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
h1, h6 {
  font-family: 'Lemon', cursive; 
  color: saddlebrown;
  text-align: center;
  }
  
  form {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.input {
  background-color: silver;
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.message {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <link href="../styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lemon&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-info bg-secondary">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="../index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="resume.html">Resume</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact Me</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
    <h1>Contact Me</h1>
    <p>Please feel free to send any questions or offers on my potential works! Make sure you include which piece you would be interested in purchasing. Serious inquiries only!</p>
    
    <form>
      <label for="userName"></label>
      <input type="text" id="userName" name="name" class="input" placeholder="Full Name"><br>
      <label for="userEmail" class="label"></label>
      <input type="email" id="userEmail" name="email" class="input" placeholder="Email Address"><br>
      <label for="userMessage" class="label"></label>
      <textarea type="text" id="userMessage" name="message" class="input message" placeholder="Message"></textarea><br>
      <input type="submit"></input>
    </form>
     
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="../scripts/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works now. Can't believe I was beating my head against the wall and it was just a missing id and some syntax issues

Answer (score 1):

When debugging JS always open the console output of devtools, generally done by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>, and check for errors.

In this case you have a few syntax issues:

- The `)` after the function definition is in the wrong place and should be removed.
- There needs to be a `)` after the event handler function body to close the `submit()` method call
- There's no `submit` id on the button, so the event will not be bound. You need to add that id for this code to work
- A better approach would be to use the `submit` event of the `form` element instead of the click of the submit button
- Use CSS to change style when an element is hovered instead of JS, as the former performs much better.

With all that said, try this:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  e.prebentDefault(); // stop the form submission while testing. Remove this line afterwards

  alert("Thank you for your message! I will respond as soon as I find somewhere with free wifi!");
  var userName = $("#userName").val();
  var userEmail = $("#userEmail").val();
  var userMessage = $("#userMessage").val();
})
```

```css
.contact-header:hover {
  color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your event looks okay minus a couple of syntax errors.

Cleaned it up a bit:

```js
$("#submit").click(function () {
  alert("Thank you for your message! I will respond as soon as I find somewhere with free wifi!");
  var userName = $("#userName").val();
  var userEmail = $("#userEmail").val();
  var userMessage = $("#userMessage").val();
})

$(".contact-header").hover(function () {
  $(".contact-header").css("color", "black");                          
})
```

As for your question about the alert. The `$("#submit").click` is perfectly fine with how you have written it. However, the button you are waiting for does not have the ID to match "submit".

In your form, you have this:

```html
<input type="submit"></input>
```

However, to get the event to work correctly, you need to add an `id` attribute to it, so the JQuery can find the button correctly. Like so:

```html
<input id="submit" type="submit"></input>
```

The logic behind that is your JQuery is looking for a HTML element with the `id` of "submit": `$("#submit")`. The # means it will search for an ID. Now if you did something like this: `$(".submit")` it would search for an element with the `submit` class. E:G:

```html
<input class="submit" type="submit"></input>
```

Take a look at how to get your elements via JQuery if you need to here: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/